# How to use Unreal 4 ProceduralMeshComponent classes in code?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, procedural-generation

I was trying to find some examples or documentation as for how to implement functionality using the Unreal 4 ProceduralMeshComponents through code. The documentation of these classes on the website is very sparse and only provides the barest details of how they function:

https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/BlueprintAPI/Components/ProceduralMesh/index.html

I know, I know, they are already exposed to the Blueprint Editor so I am aware I can use them in the engine itself. However, I want to understand the exact ins and outs of the process, which means that I need to implement this in a project through code.

Also I feel that using these components through Blueprint nodes alone limits the extent of what can be done with this powerful functionality.

I have also made searches for any examples (either on the net or on the forums) but can't find any that don't involve using Blueprints in some way. The other problem is that this functionality was introduced relatively recently, and before this Rama (a stellar Unreal user) had put up a similar API that allowed procedural mesh generation. However it is deprecated now and there are many examples that refer to that version instead.

Don't get me wrong, I'm not dissing Blueprints here. I love the tool and consider them one of the best bits of Unreal 4. But for my purpose I require the process to be completely exposed to me from start to finish.

I would appreciate any resources or examples that you could share that implement the Unreal Procedural Mesh classes completely through code towards some effect.

Comment: Here are some procedural mesh object creation examples https://github.com/SiggiG/ProceduralMeshDemos

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a big question, since Procedural Mesh Components can be used in very many ways. They just represent an arbitrary runtime-generated mesh.

Most of the functions listed in the documentation are quite self-explanatory if you know the data representations of meshes in 3D applications.

A mesh can have several LODs. Each individual mesh LOD is made up of sections. Each section can have a visual representation and a collision representation. For the "visual" representation, there are lists of point locations, lists of triangles that are represented by three point indices, lists of edges connecting two points, lists of normals for each triangle, lists of UV-space positions for each point, etc. For "collision" representation of the meshes, there are of course separate lists, in most cases smaller in size for more optimized calculation.

Depending on your use case, you fill these lists with the data you need. This data can be generated in whatever way of course, that is up to you. Whatever you do, you just need to have some arrays of the needed stuff, be it points, edges, etc.

> can't find any that don't involve using Blueprints in some way

The beauty of UE is, any “blueprint” example can act as a C++ example. You can recreate a BP graph on code easily one-to-one, since BP nodes are based on C++ functions which are marked as `UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)`. For the C++ versions of the functions, you can see the C++ source by double clicking the node.

p.s. I understand it might not be the best that I don't provide you code examples, but instead a long-winded explanation, but for a question this wide there's really no one-size-fits-all code snippet.

Plus, procedural mesh generation is a massive world of its own, with each individual scenario requiring thousands of lines of specialized code. If you make a procedural terrain vs a procedural animal vs a procedural chair, you can imagine the code is both very complex and so specific it's nearly useless for the other use cases.

Comment: To add a tip, you should also look into Runtime Mesh Component. It’s a free and open source component with very similar functionality to the PMC, but more optimised. It has an active discord, and good documentation.